# Include name in product image URL with mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, imageurl

I have image URLs like this:

/p/sh-9001.jpg

but I want to include product name in the URL for SEO so I want 
/p/sh-9001---some-product-name.jpg
to point to
/p/sh-9001.jpg

The rewrite should ignore "---" and everything after and then add ".jpg"

What is the the rewrite for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(p/.+?)--.+$ /$1.jpg [L,NC]
```

Comment: One issue. It needs to accept only "/p/". Now it accepts "p/" so "abcp/" will alse be accepted.

Comment: No `abcp/` won't be accepted, did you even test it? There is start anchor `^` which means only `/p/...` is matched. Leading slash is omitted in htaccess.